# Как получить переменные экземпляра класса вне?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Внутри экземпляра переменные можно получить с помощью функции locals(), которая возвращает словарь. Вопрос: как получить переменные экземпляра класса, при этом не "находясь" в нём?

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

hello = Hello(5)
print(hello.locals()) # {'self': .., 'i': 5}
```

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: `hello.__dict__` ?

Comment: что означает "не находясь в нем"?

Comment: @Эникейщик, если выполняется код, который находится в самом классе, то в код можно добавить функцию locals() для получения локальных переменных, за пределами класса locals() будет работать, но она будет возвращать не то, что я хочу получить.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [vars()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) из стандартной библиотеки python.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

hello = Hello(5)
variables = vars(hello)

print(variables)
```

> {'i': 5}

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]